# How can i disable the ctrl + a using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function mischandler(){
return false;
}

function mousehandler(e){
var myevent = (isNS) ? e : event;
var eventbutton = (isNS) ? myevent.which : myevent.button;
if((eventbutton==2)||(eventbutton==3)) return false;
}
document.oncontextmenu = mischandler;
document.onmousedown = mousehandler;
document.onmouseup = mousehandler;
var isCtrl = false;
    document.onkeyup=function(e)
    {
    if(e.which == 17)
    isCtrl=false;
    }

    document.onkeydown=function(e)
    {
    if(e.which == 17)
    isCtrl=true;
    if((e.which == 85) || (e.which == 67) && isCtrl == true)
    {
    // alert(‘Keyboard shortcuts are cool!’);
    return false;
    }
    }

</script>
```

Hi all , I using the code to disable the right click and also the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> how to disable the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> in the following code. Any help would be great.

Thanks,
vicky

Comment: This is hopelessly impossible.  Don't bother trying.

Comment: That is some nice old code since Netscape has not been relevant in years.

Comment: Please, _never_ try to stop users from doing what they are used to, it will only annoy them and make them stop using your site

Comment: you're definitely not the first one to try this either, there are a million people who already have working implementations available

(like 10 seconds of googling informed me : )

http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/disable-ctrl-n-and-other-ctrl-key-combinations-in-javascript.html

Comment: if you're looking for a great key-binding library, I suggest https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys it's very nice ;)

Comment: You're supporting Netscape? Are you sending this website back to the 90s?

Comment: If its text you don't want to be able to select, may I suggest CSS.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FInd the below code for detect ctrl + a,ctrl + A,ctrl + c,ctrl + C, ctrl + u,ctrl + U with your code editing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isNS = (navigator.appName == "Netscape") ? 1 : 0;

if(navigator.appName == "Netscape") document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN||Event.MOUSEUP);

function mischandler(){
return false;
}

function mousehandler(e){
var myevent = (isNS) ? e : event;
var eventbutton = (isNS) ? myevent.which : myevent.button;
if((eventbutton==2)||(eventbutton==3)) return false;
}
document.oncontextmenu = mischandler;
document.onmousedown = mousehandler;
document.onmouseup = mousehandler;
var isCtrl = false;
document.onkeyup=function(e)
{
if(e.which == 17)
isCtrl=false;
}

document.onkeydown=function(e)
{
if(e.which == 17)
isCtrl=true;
if(((e.which == 85) || (e.which == 117) || (e.which == 65) || (e.which == 97) || (e.which == 67) || (e.which == 99)) && isCtrl == true)
{
// alert(‘Keyboard shortcuts are cool!’);
return false;
}
}
```

you can get value for key from below link

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html
Enjoy...!! :)

Answer (score 13):

You shouldn't try to do this, let me tell you why. I'm assuming you want to disable <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> because you don't want the user to be able to copy content from your site, well have you thought about the fact that there are a dozen of other ways to copy your content?

1. Download html file and copy in their  favorite text editor
2. Inspect element and copy content from there
3. Use mouse to right click -> copy

And for my good friend *@glenatron*:

1. Network sniffer like Fiddler between the browser and the network card
2. Screenshots, Taking a photograph of the monitor

**... The list goes on and on.**

Also, trying to stop users from *normal* functionality will only bother and annoy them; *most likely causing them to leave your site and never return*.

Comment: Network sniffer like Fiddler between the browser and the network card, Screenshots, Taking a photograph of the monitor...

Comment: @glenatron Should I add? :p The list could go on for days and days

Answer (score 1):

> How can i disable the ctrl + a

I had the same question but for a different reason,

I had multiple [`textPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath) elements in my DOM and because of some weird bug, whenever I pressed ctrl + a they all change position, to fix that I added:

```
body{
   ...

   user-select:none    
}
```

I guess this also "technically" disables Ctrl + a