# Disable Ctrl key in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, disabled-control

I want to disable the ctrl key in the IE browser.I had tried some solution using javascript but nothing is working can someone please help me to find out the solution

```js
document.onkeydown = function () { 
  if (event.keyCode == 17) alert('Ctrl Key is disabled'); 
};


document.onkeydown = function(e) {
         if (e.altKey && (e.keyCode === 36)) {//Alt+home blocked.
            return false;
        }
        if (e.altKey && (e.keyCode === 70)) {//Alt+f blocked.
            return false;
        }
    };


function hookKeyboardEvents(e) {
    // get key code
    var key_code = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.which;

    // case :if it is IE event
    if (window.event)
    {
        if (!event.shiftKey && !event.ctrlKey) {
            window.event.returnValue = null;
            event.keyCode = 0;
        }
    }
    // case: if it is firefox event
    else
        e.preventDefault();
}

window.document.onkeydown = hookKeyboardEvents;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280582/how-can-i-disable-the-ctrl-a-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function Disable_Control_C() {
var keystroke = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();

if (event.ctrlKey && (keystroke == 'c' || keystroke == 'v' || keystroke == 'p' || keystroke == 's' || keystroke == 'u')) {
alert("this function is disabled");
event.returnValue = false; // disable Ctrl+C
}
}
```

```html
<body onkeydown="javascript:Disable_Control_C()">
```

this is what i do it to run in the IE...